# Convert bash prompt in Terminal to zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

I had recently updated Terminal to use zsh, after doing so the prompt on new terminal windows now displays: `\[\033[1;92m\]\h:\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;34m\][\W]\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;31m\]\u$\[\033[0m\]` rather than customized prompt I had set up previously.

Any suggestions for updating the bash profile to display customized prompts again within Terminal or cleaning up the default Terminal prompt to display desired device name, path, etc. using the zsh-based profile?

Comment: `zsh` doesn't read `bash_profile`. https://zsh-prompt-generator.site/ can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Prompt escape sequences are different in [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) and [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Simple-Prompt-Escapes). The functionality is similar, but the syntax is completely different. You need to translate your bash setting to zsh syntax.

The prompt goes into the `PS1` variable in both cases. (There are other possibilities but you don't need to use them.) The setting goes into `.zshrc`. So you need to add a line like this to your `.zshrc`:

```
PS1=$'%{\e[1;92m%}%m:…'
```

I started the translation: bash's `\[…\]` around zero-width constructs becomes zsh's `%{…%}`, the escape character expressed as `\033` in bash is `$'\e'` in zsh, the host name is `\h` in bash and `%m` in zsh...

Comment: In `zsh`, you'd rather use `%B%F{10}` or `%B%F{#00ff00}` to say bold and bright green foreground.

Answer (score 1):

`\e[92m` is the sequence to set foreground colour to colour 10 (bright green) on those terminals that support 16 (or more) ANSI colours. That's the sequence sent by `echoti setaf 10` (terminfo) or `echotc AF 10` (termcap) for instance (also `tput setaf 10` or `tput AF 10` depending on the system) when `$TERM` refers to  such a terminal.

`\e[1m` is the one for *bold*.

In `zsh` prompt expansion,

- `%B` it to turn *bold* on, `%b` to turn it off.
- `%10F` to set the foreground colour 10, `%F{#00ff00}` for RGB specifications (for terminals that support it, `zmodload zsh/nearcolor` can be used to get the nearest colour from the palette for those that don't support it), `%f` to reset to the default foreground colour. `%F{blue}` works for the basic 8 lower colors (`\e[3xm`).
- equivalent of bash's `\h`, `\W`, `\u` should be `%m`, `%~`, `%n` like in tcsh

So the equivalent of bash's

```
\[\033[1;92m\]\h:\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;34m\][\W]\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;31m\]\u$\[\033[0m\]
```

Should be something like:

```
%10F%B%m: %b%4F[%~] %1F%n$ %f
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to set the prompt in `Zsh` without using so many confusing backslashes is just to use `tput` command. For example, here is how you would set the prompt string to bold with a foreground color of yellow:

```
promptText="megh$ "
PS1="%{$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 3)%}$promptText%{$(tput sgr0)%}"
```

To escape the unprintable characters, one needs to put them inside `%{ ... %}` in Zsh. For Bash, put them inside `\[ ... \]` or `\001 ... \002` instead.

More explained [here](https://medium.com/@megh319/configure-terminal-prompt-with-colors-for-macos-3ea7b62ed076)

Comment: zsh has `echoti` as a builtin (and more portable) version of `tput`, but also prompt directives to set graphic rendering attributes, so you should not need to use those in zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `tput` is one way of doing this. If you have another solution, you are welcome to put it as another answer.

Comment: Sure. see [my answer](/a/763132).

Comment: Not sure if you read the first line of my answer. It's just too many backslashes and color codes, hence the suggestion to use `tput`. What I mean is, if you have a simpler way to do the same using `echoti`, please add that as another answer.

Comment: And I'm saying using `echoti` (let alone `tput` which is an external command and not portable) is not needed as `%{$(tput setaf 10)%}` is just `%10F` in zsh.

Comment: I am still not sure why you are so adamant over using `echoti` over `tput`. `tput` is part of the standard UNIX operating system command. It is verbose, yes, but that's what this answer is about. It is just a different way of setting the shell prompt which works. You are simply enforcing that this answer is redundant, which is not the case.

Comment: [The only capabilities that the standard mandate tput support are `clear`,`init` and `reset`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tput.html#tag_20_131_05) and only in the POSIX locale. I am "adamant" of using neither tput nor echoti nor echotc, not of using echoti