# .bashrc conflicting with Zsh

Tags: bash, arch-linux, zsh, tty

I used bash for a long time, now I want to use zsh, only one problem: .bashrc conflicts with zsh

How it is supposed to look like:

```
archcoolC#
```

How it looks like with a bashrc: (with colors here, (echo $PS1))

```
\[[1m\]\[[38;5;1m\][\[[38;5;3m\]\u\[[38;5;2m\]@\[[38;5;4m\]\h \[[38;5;5m\]\W\[[38;5;1m\]]\[[38;5;7m\]\$ \[[m(B\]
```

Anyone knows the fix?

FYI: this is on arch and on ubuntu

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code. Use [code formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead. You also might want to add the output of `echo $PS1`.

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to set `PS1` for `zsh` in the same way as you would set it for `bash` (or you export it, for whatever reason). This won't work. Can't say anything more really, because you never show what you're doing in your `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Similar: [Convert bash prompt in Terminal to zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/649558)

Answer (score 3):

Zsh comes with colored prompts out of box.Try

```
autoload -U promptinit && promptinit
```

then `prompt -l` lists available prompts, `-p fire` previews the "fire" prompt, `-s fire` sets it. When you are ready add a prompt add  below the autoload line above:

```
prompt fade red
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't export the PS1 shell variable, it's not meant to be exported and the few programs that usually use PS1 are other unix shells that usually have their own prompt escapes to display things.

Comment: Okay, unexporting it fixed the problem, but what if I want to have colors in the zsh prompt?